# Create correct query with Spring data mongodb queryDSL

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I Try to create correct query to mondo db in spring data mongodb. I have this entity:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(collection = "test")
@Data
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("f1")
    private String f1;

    @Field("f2")
    private String f2;

    @Field("f3")
    private String f3;
}
```

I generated `queryDSL` class for this entity and tried to create a request from the builder.
I tried different combinations and it is the last below.

```
QTest test = QTest.test;
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();

booleanBuilder.and(test.name.eq("Name"));

BooleanBuilder foo = new BooleanBuilder();
foo
  .and(
    test.f1.contains("abc")
      .or(
        test.f2.contains("abc").or(test.f3.contains("abc"))
      )
  )
  .and(
    test.f1.contains("asd")
      .or(
        test.f2.contains("asd").or(test.f3.contains("asd"))
      )
  );
booleanBuilder.and(foo);

QPageRequest request = QPageRequest.of(0, 20);
Page < Test > testPage = testRepository.findAll(booleanBuilder, request);
```

It is my log output(generated query)

```
{
  '$and': [
    {
      'name': 'Name',
      '$or': [
        { 'f1': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qabc\\E.*', 'options': '' }}},
        { 'f2': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qabc\\E.*', 'options': '' }}},
        { 'f3': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qabc\\E.*', 'options': '' }}}
      ]
    },
    {
      '$or': [
        { 'f1': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qasd\\E.*', 'options': '' }}},
        { 'f2': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qasd\\E.*', 'options': '' }}},
        { 'f3': { '$regularExpression': { 'pattern': '.*\\Qasd\\E.*', 'options': '' }}}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need to get this query:

```
   {
  'name': 'Name',
  '$and': [{
      '$or': [
        { 'f1': { '$regex': '\\Qabc\\E', '$options': '' }},
        { 'f2': { '$regex': '\\Qabc\\E', '$options': '' }},
        { 'f3': { '$regex': '\\Qabc\\E', '$options': '' }}
      ]
    },
    {
      '$or': [
        { 'f1': { '$regex': '\\Qasd\\E', '$options': '' }},
        { 'f2': { '$regex': '\\Qasd\\E', '$options': '' }},
        { 'f3': { '$regex': '\\Qasd\\E', '$options': '' }}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: ```foo.and( test.name.eq("Name")).and``` is give same query as you required.

Comment: @Ashok No, it  doesn't give the same query as my required